# Broadcast web cam with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I can get stream from browser with these lines of code:

```
var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:9000');
navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                          navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                          navigator.msGetUserMedia;


var cam;
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {
    //var call = peer.call('another-peers-id', stream);
        //call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
        // Show stream in some video/canvas element.
    //});
    cam = stream;
    console.log(stream);
}, function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to get local stream' ,err);
});
```

Now I want to send live stream to socket.io server and then broadcast it with socket.io server.
Is there any simple code to do it ?

Comment: I'm wondering if socket.io 1.0 new version and the stream handling feature, we can pass a getusermedia stream, if someone have tried the feedback would be interesting

Comment: Maybe it's not exactly what you want, but you may find [socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) module useful.

Comment: I am trying the same thing; but i send screencaps of the webcam over the socket. Let me know if you can get socket.io-stream to work for it, it's a new thing that seems to be built for this.

Comment: Perhaps this question may help you how to send the stream to the server. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836741/signalr-webrtc-websocket-is-already-in-closing-or-closed-state

Comment: It seems really silly that there's no information on this. This is the first thing I thought to do when WebRTC and Socket.io were spoken in the same sentence, and yet after 3 hours of searching, no one seems to know how to do this, or why it might not be possible. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I tried for a few days to get something like this working, and after going down the rabbit hole I ended up just firing up an instance of Wowza media server on AWS (following [these instructions](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36-How-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-an-RTMP-based-encoder)) and managing the server with my node instance instead of trying to do the video.

It worked *beautifully*.  Scales well (auto-scaling even), relatively easy to deploy, and has great support on their forums.  A++, would code again.

Also, ultimately you're probably going to need to do some transcoding/scaling/watermarking if this is to be a commercial project, and Wowza leverages NVENC on the GPU on Amazon's graphics instances, which just blows anything else out of the water.

Comment: Cool, are you able to share any data on costs? Did you consider using the YouTube live streaming API?