# SignalR WebRTC WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state

Tags: websocket, html5-canvas, html5-video, signalr, webrtc

I wanted to take a test run of the simplest implementation of SignalR and WebRTC. I hosted the code in https://github.com/foyzulkarim/WebRtc

I made two different files "index.html" and "index1.html". 
In index.html I broadcasted a video file through signalr and it went very well. But when I just replace existing video file with WebCam's feed, it started getting error.

After running couple of second I start getting this error ***"WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state."*** I tried to throttle but no change, still get the error. Any idea why it might happening?

Error image
[image]

You can check the video i  http://1drv.ms/1meM1OI

Comment: at what point in the PeerConnection(from your code I am assuming a peer connection in WebRTC) do you get the error?

Comment: i don't have any peer connection. i get the feed to video tag, then display it to canvas. then get the dataUrl from the canvas. then send it to signalr for broadcast. problem is, this approach working fine with a video file, but not for the webcam feed.

Answer (score 3):

The message size seems to be the key problem here.

In your project, every frame of video is about 40k but every frame of cam is more than 140K.
Actually, in index.html when you broadcast the video, after about 20s, there will be several frames larger than 70k which will also give you the same error.

I tried sending some long string messages as a test, and I do get errors when the message is longer than a certain value. However, I was not able to find in the documentation a definite limitation of message length or message density.

Comment: I'll try to so some works according to your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I had similliar problem running websocket app server on Glassfish 4 with port 8080, After I changed my port to another it works (eg: 8887), probably this is a temporary solution before finding the permanent solution for port 8080.

Edit: Found the root cause, my antivirus was using port 80 which is used by websocket. If You find the similiar problem check your antivirus/other aplication port.

Comment: antivirus software on server side? or client side? Thanks,

Comment: Actually I am not quite sure since it was under development (client and server located at the same pc), sorry for that ...